# In Visual Studio, what steps I need to check in code retrospectively into TFS, after changes have been made

Tags: tfs, tfvc

Working in VS 2019.  I forgot to check in the original source into TFS before making changes.  So now, I need to get the original source into TFS and the changes in. What are the steps?

Source code in TFS. Latest changes in TFS as history.

Comment: Remove the repo, re-create the repo, commit and push the original, commit and push the new code.

Comment: TFS is the server, I suspect you mean TFVC as opposed to git, TFS supports both version controls to my understanding

Comment: well.. @Fildor ..  it's not clear whether there is a local repo\workspace that faciliates changes locally, or what the version control is for that matter.  OP is just articulating that they modified their code before committing to the remote (server) first

Comment: @BrettCaswell Good point. Didn't think of local repo.

Comment: Are you using TFVC or Git as your source control?

Comment: Yes @BrettCaswell VC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you hadn't checked your local code in TFS.

You could simply manually restore your changed code to original source (also remember to back up changes) and then check in your files.

Finally add your changes to local, check in pending changes. Now everything get back on track.

- If you already checked your code in TFS.

You could delete all files in local workspace and add your source code, now Visual Studio will auto detect the pending changes, you just need to check in changes.

At present, the latest changeset is your original source. You could not change the order of generated changeset. However, you could choose to [Roll back changesets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/roll-back-changesets?view=azure-devops).

> A **changeset** is a permanent part of the history of your
>   version-controlled items and **cannot be undone or removed**. However, you
>   can roll back the effects of one or more changesets.

Then your local should be original source + changes, keep working and moving forward.